# Keras predict() valueError: input doesn't have the correct dimension

Tags: python, machine-learning, keras, predict

I'm completely new to machine learning and I wanted to start with a fairly easy project: the digit recognition using the mnist data set. I'm using keras and tensorflow and I started using code I found [here](https://machinelearningmastery.com/handwritten-digit-recognition-using-convolutional-neural-networks-python-keras/).The network is built and trained correctly and I now want to make a simple prediction. For starters I simply used one of the pictures in the part of the data set meant for testing and I would like my output to be that number. (In this case the output is supposed to be 7.)
Here's my code:

```
# Baseline MLP for MNIST dataset
from tensorflow.keras.datasets import mnist
from tensorflow.keras.models import Sequential
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Dense
from keras.utils import np_utils

import numpy as np

# load data
(X_train, y_train), (X_test, y_test) = mnist.load_data()
# flatten 28*28 images to a 784 vector for each image
num_pixels = X_train.shape[1] * X_train.shape[2]
X_train = X_train.reshape((X_train.shape[0], num_pixels)).astype('float32')
X_test = X_test.reshape((X_test.shape[0], num_pixels)).astype('float32')

# normalize inputs from 0-255 to 0-1
X_train = X_train / 255
X_test = X_test / 255

# one hot encode outputs
y_train = np_utils.to_categorical(y_train)
y_test = np_utils.to_categorical(y_test)
num_classes = y_test.shape[1]


# define baseline model
def baseline_model():
    # create model
    model = Sequential()
    model.add(Dense(num_pixels, input_dim=num_pixels, kernel_initializer='normal', activation='relu'))
    model.add(Dense(num_classes, kernel_initializer='normal', activation='softmax'))
    # Compile model
    model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy', optimizer='adam', metrics=['accuracy'])
    return model

# build the model
model = baseline_model()
print("created model")

# Fit the model
model.fit(X_train, y_train, validation_data=(X_test, y_test), epochs=10, batch_size=200, verbose=2) 
print("did model.fit")


image_index=0
print("correct result : ", y_test[image_index])
print("shape of the array: ", X_test[0].shape)
print("predicted result : ", model.predict(X_test[image_index]))
```

Now I get the following error:

```
ValueError: Error when checking input: expected dense_input to have shape (784,) but got array with shape (1,)
```

although my array does have the correct shape! As you can see I print `print("shape of the array: ", X_test[0].shape)` which does return `shape of the array:  (784,)`. 784 is exactly the dimension we want and still i get that error.

I've spent hours trying to solve this but no matter what I tried (reshaping the array for example), it doesn't seem to work. Clearly there is some missunderstanding concerning either keras' predict function or the array. Can you please help me understand and solve this?
Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the predict function still expects a 0 dimension to be the sample dimension.

When you indexed X_test[0] you basically removed this dimension which causes the predict function to now have 784 samples of 1 pixel!

change your code to:

```
print("predicted result : ", model.predict(X_test[0].reshape(-1,num_pixels)))
```

Now you should have the result probabilities.

Edit:

And if you just want the maximum probability predicted number:

```
print("predicted result : ",  np.argmax(model.predict(X_test[0].reshape(-1,num_pixels)), axis = 1))
```

Comment: Thank you, this does show me the probabilities! If I want it to return the solution (7 in this case) can I do that with predict() as well or do I have to simply select the index with the highest probability?

Comment: @Johanna See edited answer above to get the predicted solution.

Answer (score 0):

ompletely new to machine learning and I wanted to start with a fairly easy project: the digit recognitiors I simply used

Comment: It looks like you posted incorrectly ...please edit to include an answer - or delete this answer (as all it is is a copy of the first few words of the question).  thanks!